# Spring MongoDB Save

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, spring-mongodb

I'm creating a Spring Boot application and I am using AngularJS on the frontend.

Upon submitting a form with the appropiate parameters, Spring is supposed to use `bookRepository.save()` method in order to save the provided data in the MongoDB. The problem is, this action gets carried on, but the structure of my model is not respected.

```
@Document(collection = "books")
public class Book {
    private String id;

    private String title;

    private String author;

    private String description;

    private String cover;

    // Getters and setters below.
}
```

The final outcome after following the above process: instead of having a record following the above structure inserted in MongoDB, I only end up with a field containing `_id` and `_class`.

Any ideas as to why is this happening?

Comment: Can you add a sample document from collection  and also the part of code where you are mapping the data to `Book` object ?

Comment: please follow this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/ and check what you have missed to include in your app

Comment: Perhaps your object is empty (i.e. all fields are null). That would explain that behaviour.